# convert jquery truncate plugin with selector into a method that can be called externally

Tags: jquery

I am trying to modify this jquery truncate plugin, so that I can:
- call it manually without using a selector
- and pass to text that I would like truncating.

Is this possible to create a public method that can be called externally?

```
/*
* Truncate a piece of text to a predefined amount of lines. 
* It assumes pixel values of both the container and its line-height. 
* Useful when you have multiple boxes with text in your design that require equal heights
*/

$.fn.truncateLines = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        delay: 100,
        text: false,
        minusHeight: 0
    };
    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    function truncate(index, container){
        container = $(container);
        var containerLineHeight = Math.ceil(parseFloat(container.css('line-height'))),
            maxHeight = options.lines * containerLineHeight,
            truncated = false,
            truncatedText = $.trim(container.text()),
            overflowRatio = container.height() / maxHeight;

        if (overflowRatio > 2) {
            // slice string based on how much text is overflowing
            truncatedText = truncatedText.substr(0, parseInt(truncatedText.length / (overflowRatio - 1), 10) + 1); 
            container.text(truncatedText);
            truncated = true;
        }
        var oldTruncatedText; // verify that the text has been truncated, otherwise you'll get an endless loop
        while (container.height() > maxHeight && oldTruncatedText != truncatedText) {
            oldTruncatedText = truncatedText;
            // remove last word
            truncatedText = truncatedText.replace(/\s.[^\s]*\s?$/, ''); 
            container.text(truncatedText);
            truncated = true;
        }
        if (truncated) {
            truncatedText = options.ellipsis ? truncatedText + options.ellipsis : truncatedText;
            container.text(truncatedText);
            if (container.height() > maxHeight) {
                // remove last word and ellipsis
                truncatedText = truncatedText.replace(/\s.[^\s]*\s?...$/, ''); 
                truncatedText = options.ellipsis ? truncatedText + options.ellipsis : truncatedText;
                container.text(truncatedText);
            }
        }
    }

    // Loop selectors
    return this.each(truncate(index, container));
};
```